# S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: .jpg

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2

Am trying file upload to s3 bucket in php.

I am uploading video .mp4 size(1 mb) to mybucket/temp folder and cut the thumb file from that video (temp folder is in s3 bucket only).

That is my code :-

```
   $video_type = strtolower(pathinfo($video_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  //Create object S3 ,File path models/S3.php
   $object_s3 = new S3(Yii::$app->params['aws_access_key'], Yii::$app->params['aws_secret_key']);
   //bucket name 
         $Amazon_Bucket = "abc-videos";
        //create image name dynamically and unique
          $uploadimage = $insert_videoid . "-thumb.jpg";
         //create video name dynamically and unique
            $uploadvideo = $insert_videoid . "-video." . $video_type;
            exec("ffmpeg -i " . $videotempname . " -deinterlace -an -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:01 -s 150x150 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg " . $uploadimage . " 2>&1");
             $thumbfile = $insert_videoid . "/thumb-" . $insert_videoid . ".jpg";
            if ($object_s3->putObjectFile($videotempname, $Amazon_Bucket, $uploadvideo, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
        //create url and update in tbl_video
           $object_s3->putObjectFile($uploadimage, $Amazon_Bucket, $thumbfile, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
           $url = "http://" . $abc . ".s3.amazonaws.com/" . $uploadvideo;
```

Comment: @Mit.agile I already tried this thing but its not working

Comment: ok .. let me go through.

Comment: it could possible the max-file in you php.ini is setted to 2MB. Have you tried to check?

Comment: yes I checked and max-file size  is 16MB

Comment: can u check and read this thread https://osclasswiki.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/fixing-the-amazon-s3-plugin-for-osclass/

Comment: I checked this document but it was also not helpful for me   :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121343/discussion-between-mit-agile-and-renu-thakur).